# Is there a way to detect whether the given image contains labeled parts?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, annotations, ocr, python-tesseract

I have a use-case to detect whether the given image contains annotated attributes or not?

For example - if I give an input image as:-

[image]

The expected output is:

1. Detection that the image contains attribute annotations
2. The attribute labels from the image (if possible)

Things tried:
I tried using OCR with the help of pytesseract but I was only able to get the words in haphazard manner. Next I tried to detect arrows/lines in the image, but that also did not work as expected, since it detects all horizontal and vertical lines but cannot differentiate between center image(printer) and arrows(used for attributes)

Any help to will be appreciated. Thank-you.

Comment: What about trying template match using some letters as template? If matches you can resolve item (1).

Comment: @dpetrini thank-you for your response. But I also have some other images(containing other words which are not required) which would go in as input, so template match would require me to have a comprehensive list of all required keywords to match after OCRing the images.